# Prove iterations of quadratic maps tends to $-\infty$

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, discrete-time

So far, I have to read about quadratic map in "Introduction to Dynamical Systems" by Brin and Stuck.

The quadratic map is
$$q_{\mu}(x) = \mu x(1-x), \quad \mu > 0.$$

Now, I need to show when $\mu > 1$ and $x \notin [0,1]$, the limit of iterations $q^n_{\mu}(x)$ tends to $-\infty$.

I read several topics on Stack discussing about quadratic map, but none of them discussed this one. The only thing I know is I can write quadratic map as
$$q^{n+1}_{\mu}(x) = \mu q^n_{\mu}(x)(1 - q^n_{\mu}(x)).$$

But, how can I continue? Please give me some advice. Thanks so much.

---

Okay, thanks to the hint from Will Jagy, I got my answers.

Fix $\mu > 0$, let $q(x) = \mu x(1-x)$ and let $x < 0$. We shall show by induction
$$q^n(x) < \mu^n x, \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

For the case $x>1$, we do the same since $(1-x)<0$.

Comment: Once $x_0 < 0$   we have $q^{(n)}  < \mu^n x_0$

Comment: and if $x_{-1}  > 1 $  then $x_0 < 0$

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Comment: Plot $q_2$ and the line $x \mapsto x$ and look at a few sample iterations.

Comment: @copper.hat I understand by image but I need a proof. Will Jagy give me some hints.